# monday of current week

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using the below SQLite expression to get the first day(Monday) of the current week :

```
DATE('now','localtime','weekday 1','-7 days')
```

The problem is if `now` is a Monday, it will return last week's Monday. For example, on 2014-11-17(17th Nov), it returns 2014-11-10(10th Nov) instead of returning the same date(2014-11-17).

Is there a correct way to get the current week's monday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DATE('now','localtime','weekday 0','-6 days')
```